# WPS/SAS how to keep column names that are imported from excel?

Tags: sas, wps

I tried to create a new data set that keeps only a few columns from one huge data set.  The new data set will have a different number of columns and I want to save them their names in excel because there will be frequent changes and I don't want to make changes to the code.

I tried to store the column names in excel - (It contains one sheet in the first column of which all the column names are stored which I want to save as the names are listed in rows).
This is my code which works but is not correct.  With this code - I import all names from excel.  But when I add it in a columns_to_keep variable and in the next step I try to save it, the new dataset keeps only the last row name.
How can I keep all columns?  Example In Excel, I add 10 column names, the new data set should also keep these 10 names for me, not 1.

```
libname excelin excel "C:\Users\Xxxxxx\Xxxxx\WPS\your_excel_file.xlsx";
data ColumnNames;
    set EXCELIN.'Sheet1$'n;
    call symputx('columns_to_keep', column);
run;

data newdata ;
    keep &columns_to_keep;
    set ACCOUNTS;
    
run;
```

Comment: What exactly does SHEET1 have in it?  Does it have one COLUMN with many ROWS?  Or one ROW with many COLUMNS?  Your code seems to think it has one COLUMN and only one ROW (or if there are many rows you only want the value in the LAST row).

Comment: It have one COLUMN with many ROWS.  I want to keep only this many rows in new data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have worksheet with a single column like this:

```
 VARNAME
 ID
 AGE
 SEX
 DOB
```

Then you can use PROC SQL and the SELECT ... INTO ... syntax to create a single macro variable with the list ID AGE SEX DOB.

```
proc sql noprint;
select nliteral(trim(varname)) into :columns_to_keep separated by ' '
  from EXCELIN.'Sheet1$'n
;
quit;
```

Comment: It worked! Many thanks!